# How can I detect a [NotMapped] annotation from PropertyInfo or MetaData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

If I have the `PropertyInfo` for a property or the MVC MetaData for that property, how can I detect whether it has the `[NotMapped]` annotation from EF CodeFirst? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achive it like that:

```
youPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), true).Count() > 1
```